# Integrating Auth0 into a Node & Express app

Tags: node.js, express, auth0

I’m using Node and Express for the backend of a mobile app (Flutter).

I’d like all authentication REST facing the client to be auth0’s, since they can handle attacks and security in general much better than me.

Sign Up -

1. Client sends a request to a signup endpoint on auth0’s server, with custom fields in addition to the existing ones.
2. On authentication success, auth0 sends an s2s to a signup endpoint on my server with the signup data, as well as a JWT token containing the auth data.
3. Auth0 incorporates the data responded from the signup endpoint on my server into the response to the client.

[image]

Sign In - Same as Sign Up basically, except there’s no need to accept custom fields from the client.

If such a flow is possible, can you please refer me to the relevant docs or otherwise help me understand how? Example implementations in node/express would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: If you use Auth0's lock (i.e. the Auth0-hosted lock page), you could add a Registration webhook that will call your server APIs when a new user is created. It won't send a JWT, but you can send a custom key that you can then check for in your APIs. With this setup, you could largely achieve your desired Signup flow.

Comment: For Sign in, this can happen entirely between your client app and Auth0. (and then you can call your APIs with that user's Auth0-generated JWT for secure communication).

Comment: What are the custom fields you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

As christian mentioned in the comments, you can use a post reg web hook. In addition, because hooks do not support social connections, you can use a rule to send a request to your server to create the user in your db. You can add a flag to the user's metadata to determine whether or not this rule runs.

https://auth0.com/docs/hooks/concepts/post-user-registration-extensibility-point

Here is another strategy: https://community.auth0.com/t/distinguish-between-first-login-and-silent-auth/32986

Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Since I'm using flutter for the front-end and you don't have an SDK supporting it, where can I find the public API of my app so that I can make the requests myself? For instance I couldn't find the signup endpoint.